# Moodle database exceeded

Tags: database, moodle

I recently got to administrate a page build with moodle. I'm having a problem with the size of database. The session table gets overloaded and makes the db exceed it's allowed size. I have to repetitively truncate it, so i won't have problems with my hosting provider. My client doesn't want to pay more, so i don't have the option of getting more space for this db.

Does moodle have any option to restrict a table's size? It would be perfect if the database (or a script) could auto-delete old data, to replace it with new data! Can i do such thing from moodle admin panel? or should i think about get a php script to do it..??

If this is a useless question, i am sorry! ..but im very new to moodle and i couldn't figure out a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Moodle options, there is a session expiration timeout setting. This setting determines when inactive sessions expire. Is it possible to trying shortening this time period? That might help clear it out. You could also try increasing the frequency which certain cron jobs are run, as this may clear out unneeded data as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I did found an option in mydomail.com/admin/settings.php where you can choose to store session data in db or not. There was also the session expiration timeout, which i left to 30 min. I am a little skeptic about unchecking the "use db for session data" option..if i do, won't it give me any problem with the host provider?

Comment: You should most likely check with both the host and any other relevant parties before proceeding. I am not aware of what the effects are of storing session data in the DB vs not. And regardless of what anyone tells you, in my experience these questions are best answered by testing in a separate testing instance (usually a clone of a live instance, including user data and accounts).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I went for coding. I created a php script that connects to my db, truncates the responsive table of exceeding db limit, ..than disconnects safely. Set it as a cron job, once a week. Best regards!